# переменные не обьявлены, но работают

Tags: javascript, функции, переменные

На этот раз у меня вопрос в образовательных целях...
Итак, есть у меня функция:

```
function caption_building(caption, i, flag) {
  switch (caption) {
    case 'DONJON ROOMS':
      text = ROOMS_UPGRADE_INFO[i]
      data = Object.assign(BUILDINGS.rooms[i])
      pageInfoID = 1;
    break;
    case 'CASTLE BUILDING':
      text = BUILDINGS_UPGRADE_INFO[i]
      data = Object.assign(BUILDINGS.castle[i])
      pageInfoID = 2;
    break;
    case 'LANDS BUILDING':
      text = LANDS_UPGRADE_INFO[i]
      data = Object.assign(BUILDINGS.lands[i])
      pageInfoID = 3;
      break;
  }
  if (flag == 'bonus') {
    return text;
  } else {
    return data;
  }
}
```

И есть две функции, которые используют результаты ее выполнения:

```
let pageInfoID;
function page_bonus_info(el, i) {
  let caption = el.closest('#tableBuildimg').caption.textContent
  let text = caption_building(caption, i, 'bonus')
  document.getElementById('buildaing_page').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('building_bonus_page').style.display = 'block';

  printText('bonus_text', text)
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function upgrade_build(el, i) {
  let div_id = el.closest('div').id
  let caption = el.closest('#tableBuildimg').caption.textContent
  let data = caption_building(caption, i, 'upgrade')

  document.getElementById(div_id).style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('building_upgrade_page').style.display = 'block';
  print_necessary_to_upgrade(data)
}
```

И может прозвучит странно, но почему первая функция работает, когда я не обьявил ни `text`, ни `data`, они так же не являются глобальными переменными, которые находились бы за пределами этих функций? По идее должна произойти ошибка, но все работает просто идеально... Обьясните мне, почему?

Comment: А Вы используете `use strict` ?

Comment: @Vladyslav, простите, я не знаю, что такое `use strict`... Я все еще только изучаю основы программирования.

Comment: Если строгий режим не включён, произойдёт неявное объявление переменной и она будет назначена глобальному объекту............. `use strict`  - это строгий режим работы js, где такие вольности не дозволяются и скрипт кинет ошибку, как и полагается в адекватных языках программирования

Comment: А работает оно так потому, что раньше, в далёкие волосатые времена, технически имелась возможность так писать переменные. Но от этого возникает много проблем. Сейчас до сих пор это позволяется, потому что много кода так написано и если запретить сразу - всё у всех обвалится

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, а почему оно тогда ругается в других функциях? Прокатило лишь в этом кусочке кода и я никак не могу понять почему? Строгий режим отключен. Спасибо за разьяснение.

Comment: @drakoblack я не ясновидящий. надо разбирать конкретно что там где написано и что как за чем подключено и на что конкретно ругается и каким именно текстом ругается

Comment: Судя по всему действительно происходило неявно обьявление переменных.

Comment: `Необъявленные переменные всегда глобальны` источник: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var а ключевые слова `var let const` не столько объявления, сколько банальные модификаторы доступа. а сама суть функций в полном игнорировании всего что не передано явно аргументами, и в полном сокрытии всего что не было явно возвращено из них return'ом(yeld появился позже в генераторах). потому и настройки видимости там не имеют смысла. современные же функции, это уже ощутимо иная сущность в т.ч. для которой, только недавно `strict mode` подвезли. ну как то так...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значит они глобальные.

```js
function f() {
  smth = 10
}

f()
console.log(smth)
```